# Randomise time in date field for each unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time

I am trying to randomize the time in the date field based on the ID field but can't seem to work out how. I am using SQL server.

What I have now:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 144929 | 2020-01-28 00:00:00.000 |
| 144929 | 2020-01-28 00:00:00.000 |
| 144928 | 2020-01-28 00:00:00.000 |
| 144928 | 2020-01-28 00:00:00.000 |

What I need:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 144929 | 2020-01-28 15:00:00.000 |
| 144929 | 2020-01-28 15:00:00.000 |
| 144928 | 2020-01-28 16:00:00.000 |
| 144928 | 2020-01-28 16:00:00.000 |

The end goal is to have random time added to dates based on their ID but each ID has to have a unique time and date.

Many thanks.

Comment: So you want to add a random number of hours to existing dates?  What database are you using?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, what time is represented in the last two rows.  The values do not look correct.

Comment: I don't mind the time. I just want the dates to be unique based on the ID. could be different seconds or minutes.

Comment: @AlexK its SQL server and that's correct but I need it to be random but each ID has the same date and random time.

Comment: What sort of "`time`" is `30:00:00`? There's only 24 hours in a day.

Comment: it was a mistake from my end. updated now.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server you can do:

`DATEADD(day, RAND(), Date)`

If you want exact o'clock hours you can use this:

`DATEADD(hour, ROUND(RAND() * 24, 0), Date)`

---

*EDIT: I understand you have multiple IDs and want the same value for each*

You can try this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table t
JOIN (
    SELECT ID, Date = DATEADD(day, RAND(), MIN(Date))
    FROM Table t
    GROUP BY t.ID
) Dates ON Dates.ID = t.ID;
```

Due to the way the optimizer deals with side-affecting functions such as `RAND()`, you may be forced to dump the sub-query into a temp table first before joining.

Comment: thank you but it still won't change the hour based on the ID

Comment: @WisamBarakat Sorry if you explain the logic of how to adjust I will edit

Comment: I need it to add random hours for each ID. so  ID with value 144929  will have the date as 2020-01-28 15:00:00.000 and ID with value 144928 will have the date 2020-01-28 16:00:00.000
but in the code you sent, each unique date has a random hour. hope that makes sense. thank you.

Comment: Just worked you out, think I got it right. Ah I see you commented

Comment: Thank so much. I tried to run the code above but I get the Column 'database.table.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause error.

Comment: @WisamBarakat Sorry forgot the aggregation

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: updated so the Date column doesn't change, only the TIME portion of the DATETIME varies by ID]

If you add the ID value as 'seconds' using the `DATEADD` function the resultant TIME will be different for each ID.  The TIME is then converted to `DATETIME` and added to the [Date] column (also converted to 'DATETIME`.  Not sure if this qualifies as "random" tho.  Something like this

```
drop table if exists #tTest;
go
create table #tTest(
  ID        int not null,
  [Date]    date not null);

insert into #tTest values
(144929, '2020-01-28'),
(144929, '2020-01-28'),
(144928, '2020-01-28'),
(144928, '2020-01-28');

select ID, cast([Date] as datetime)+
           cast(cast(dateadd(second, ID, '00:00:00') AS time) as datetime) dtm
from #tTest;
```

```
ID      dtm
144929  2020-01-28 16:15:29.000
144929  2020-01-28 16:15:29.000
144928  2020-01-28 16:15:28.000
144928  2020-01-28 16:15:28.000
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, problem is some of my IDs are string. so this won't work for them.

Comment: What is the column type of the ID?  Could it be text like 'abc' or it's integers stored as text?

Comment: Thank you Steve, that actually worked as the ids that had text in them already have random time for their dates. so I only applied this for the dates with integer IDs. many thanks.